# Firebase Auth with ReactNative Redux not working using Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, callback, expo

I'm trying to implement the Firebase Auth in my Project, I was able to do it (at least for Email and Password Auth in Firebase) through the REST API from Firebase. However, I need to work with Social Authentication (Facebook and Google, besides Email and Password at least).

I'm using ***EXPO*** for my project (that is why I don't have the Folders of iOS or Android).

I have already install Firebase Dependency in my package.json:

[image: Firebase Dependency]

I have also initialized Firebase on my App:

FirebaseKeys.js File:

```
export default {
    firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: "[myApi Key]",
        authDomain: "alianzafc2021.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://alianzafc2021-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "alianzafc2021",
        storageBucket: "alianzafc2021.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "[Messaging ID]",
        appId: "[App ID]",
        measurementId: "[Measurement ID}]"
      }
}
```

App.js: ***(Where I initialize the Firebase)***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

//Firebase Initialize Config
import firebaseConfig from "./constants/FireBaseKeys";

//Navigation
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator";

//import de reducers
import jugadoresReducer from "./store/reducers/jugadores";
import noticiasReducer from "./store/reducers/noticias";
import partidosReducer from "./store/reducers/partido";
import tablaReducer from "./store/reducers/tabla";
import authReducer from "./store/reducers/auth";

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  jugadores: jugadoresReducer,
  noticias: noticiasReducer,
  partidos: partidosReducer,
  tabla: tablaReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

//Recibe la Tipografia de numeros
const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'number': require('./assets/fonts/number.ttf'),
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(true);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading 
      startAsync={fetchFonts} 
      onFinish={() => {
        setFontLoaded(true);
      }} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I also have created the login page without functionality (Just trying to Login which is giving the Error):

```
    import React, {useState,useCallback} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import FormInput from '../components/UI/FormInput';
import FormButton from '../components/UI/FormButton';
import SocialButton from '../components/UI/SocialButton';
import * as authActions from '../store/actions/auth';

const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const LoginHandler = useCallback ( async (email, password) => {
      setError(null);
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            await dispatch(authActions.login(email,password));
            //props.navigation.navigate('Shop');
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }, [dispatch, setEmail, setPassword]);

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={require('../assets/alianza-logo.png')}
        style={styles.logo}
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>Albo App</Text>

      <FormInput
        labelValue={email}
        onChangeText={(userEmail) => setEmail(userEmail)}
        placeholderText="Correo"
        iconType="user"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
      />

      <FormInput
        labelValue={password}
        onChangeText={(userPassword) => setPassword(userPassword)}
        placeholderText="Contraseña"
        iconType="lock"
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />

      <FormButton
        buttonTitle="Ingresar"
        onPress={LoginHandler(email, password)}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.forgotButton} onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={styles.navButtonText}>Olvidaste la Contraseña?</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {Platform.OS === 'android' ? (
        <View>
          <SocialButton
            buttonTitle="Ingresa con Facebook"
            btnType="facebook"
            color="#4867aa"
            backgroundColor="#e6eaf4"
            onPress={() => {}}
          />

          <SocialButton
            buttonTitle="Ingresa con Google"
            btnType="google"
            color="#de4d41"
            backgroundColor="#f5e7ea"
            onPress={() => {}}
          />
        </View>
      ) : null}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.forgotButton}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
        <Text style={styles.navButtonText}>
          Crear una Cuenta
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 50,
    marginTop: 30

  },
  logo: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 28,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: '#051d5f',
  },
  navButton: {
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  forgotButton: {
    marginVertical: 35,
  },
  navButtonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#2e64e5'
  },
});
```

[image: Login Page]

Now my problem is that I'm not able to give the Functionality to save some info upon login on my Reducer (or even reach the login event on my Actions).

Here is my Actions file ***(I comment out the code which works when using the Rest API to Login I have modified just the login function)***:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import Auth from "firebase/firebase-auth";

//export const SIGNUP = 'SIGNUP';
//export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
export const AUTHENTICATE = 'AUTHENTICATE';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';
export const SET_DID_TRY_AL = 'SET_DID_TRY_AL';

let timer;

export const setDidTryAL = () => {
    return { type: SET_DID_TRY_AL };
};

export const authenticate = (userId, token, expiryTime) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setLogoutTimer(expiryTime));
        dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATE, userId: userId, token: token });
    }
}

export const signup = (email, password) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[Here my ID Key]', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password,
                returnSecureToken: true,
            })
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorResData = await response.json();
            const errorId = errorResData.error.message;
            let message = 'Algo salio mal!';
            if (errorId === 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
                message = 'Este Correo ya esta en Uso';
            }
            throw new Error(message);
        }

        const resData = await response.json();
        console.log(resData.localId);
        dispatch(
            authenticate(
                resData.localId,
                resData.idToken,
                parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
            )
        );
        const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000);
        saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirationDate);
    };
};

export const login = (email, password) => {

    return async dispatch => {
     await firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(resData => {
                console.log(resData);
                dispatch(
                    authenticate(
                        resData.localId,
                        resData.idToken,
                        parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000,
                    )
                )
                const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000);
                saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirationDate);
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    }

    // return async dispatch => {
    //     const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[Here my ID Key]', {
    //         method: 'POST',
    //         headers: {
    //             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //         },
    //         body: JSON.stringify({
    //             email: email,
    //             password: password,
    //             returnSecureToken: true,
    //         })
    //     });
    //     if (!response.ok) {
    //         const errorResData = await response.json();
    //         const errorId = errorResData.error.message;
    //         let message = 'Algo salio mal!';
    //         if (errorId === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND') {
    //             message = 'Este Correo no esta en Uso';
    //         } else if (errorId === 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
    //             message = 'Esta Contraseña esta Equivocada.'
    //         }

    //         throw new Error(message);
    //     }

    //     const resData = await response.json();
    //     console.log(resData);
    //     dispatch(
    //         authenticate(
    //             resData.localId,
    //             resData.idToken,
    //             parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000,
    //         )
    //     );
    //     const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000);
    //     saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirationDate);
    // };
};

export const logout = () => {
    clearLogoutTimer();
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('userData');
    return { type: LOGOUT };
};

const clearLogoutTimer = () => {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
};

const setLogoutTimer = expirationTime => {
    return dispatch => {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(logout());
        }, expirationTime);
    };
}

const saveDataToStorage = (token, userId, expirationDate) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({
        token: token,
        userId: userId,
        expiryDate: expirationDate.toISOString(),
    }))
};

export const recoverPassword = (email) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=[Here my ID Key]', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                requestType: "PASSWORD_RESET",
                email: email
            })
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorResData = await response.json();
            const errorId = errorResData.error.message;
            let message = 'Algo salio mal!';
            if (errorId === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND') {
                message = 'Este Correo no esta en Uso';
            }
            throw new Error(message);
        }

        const resData = await response.json();
    };
};
```

And Also my Reducer:

```
import { AUTHENTICATE, LOGOUT, SET_DID_TRY_AL } from "../actions/auth";

const initialState = {
    token: null,
    userId: null,
    didTryAutoLogin: false,
};

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTHENTICATE:
            return{
                token: action.token,
                userId: action.userId,
                didTryAutoLogin: true,
            };
        case SET_DID_TRY_AL:
            return {
                ...state,
                didTryAutoLogin: true,
            }
        case LOGOUT:
            return {
                ...initialState,
                didTryAutoLogin: true,
            };
       // case SIGNUP:
        //    return{
         //       token: action.token,
         //       userId: action.userId,
         //   };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

The ***Error*** that I'm getting is:

*Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.*

I tried solving adding a Callback function, but is still giving the same issue and doesn't allow me to get even to the dispatch of my function on Actions.

Any Ideas what can I do for this?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

The error of too many re-render is here:

You should never call onPress like that on render method.

It's missing an callback function in onPress like `onPress={() => yourFunction()}` and you are calling like `onPress={yourFunction()}`

**Original:**

```js
      <FormButton
        buttonTitle="Ingresar"
        onPress={LoginHandler(email, password)}
      />
```

**Correct**

```js
      <FormButton
        buttonTitle="Ingresar"
        onPress={() => LoginHandler(email, password)}
      />
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for that it does solve for the issue with the multiple Calls, any idea on the Login function, as now it gets to the login but seems that doesn't do nothing with the code of :

Comment: `return async dispatch => {
     await firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(resData => {
                console.log(resData);
                dispatch(
                    authenticate(
                        resData.localId,
                        resData.idToken,
                        parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000,
                    )
                )`

Comment: `           const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000);
                saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirationDate);
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    }`

Comment: In login action you can't return async. You should return like that `return (dispatch) => {...}`

Comment: Thank you Erick, I still seem not able to get to ResData Console Log to see that it sends the info I need to the Reducer, to proceed with Login, any other idea?

Comment: Remember to remove the await from firebase call `await firebase`. You don't get any errors in `catch()`?

Comment: I did remove the await just left firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)  and the rest but don't get neither errors or the console log nothing

Comment: Did you import firebase correctly? Because I just saw this import there `import Auth from "firebase/firebase-auth";`

Comment: I thought of that so I changed it to `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` and I think is working because when I type firebase. the system gives me the possible functions I'm looking for (auth, database, firestore, functions, initializeApp, messaging, performance, registerVersion, remoteConfig, storage). I even tried doing the initializeApp again in this file but still not getting anything.

Comment: having the exact same issue... when i worked on firebase + redux using Expo 2 years ago, using the same codes it worked. now it doesn't